# How to put data from multiple rows into one row array in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table `days` which specifies the breakfast food and dinner food for each day, using IDs that point to a table `food` which contains the food names. How do I fetch the breakfast and dinner food names using a single query? Basically I want to combine the following into one query:

```
SELECT days.*, food.name AS breakfast_name FROM days, food WHERE days.breakfast_id = food.id AND days.id = '12'
SELECT days.*, food.name AS dinner_name FROM days, food WHERE days.dinner_id = food.id AND days.id = '12'
```

Comment: A properly normalized data structure would make this a lot easier. That is you'd have a one-to-many join table between `days` and `food` with some kind of `type` column that can be used for grouping like this. You've violated the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) by having *two* join columns.

Comment: Can you give the structure and data samples from both tables?  It may help get a better understanding of what you need.  Also, how many columns do you expect in the combined query?  I'm assuming you're not only looking to do a simple union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a single query by joining the food table twice on the separate ids.

```
SELECT days.*, bf.name AS breakfast_name, df.name AS dinner_name FROM days JOIN food AS bf ON days.breakfast_id=bf.id JOIN food AS df ON days.dinner_id=df.id;
```